# Macros preincrement in c++

Tags: c++, macros

1.macros has always been difficult.
2.Below is the code and output is 125 and 7....Please elaborate the working

```
#define mul(x) (x++ * ++x * x++)
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{
    int a=4,j;
    j=mul(a);
    cout<<j<<endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your macro is not the problem; the code within it is. You're invoking undefined behavior... research _sequence points_ to learn more.

Comment: This is not a "we solve your homework" site. Nobody's ever going to write something like this in production code. (I really hope so!!)

Comment: There's nothing really to elaborate besides the result being undefined behavior. The compiler is free to return any number (or, indeed generate code that crashes)

Comment: Not again a person writing daft code in another form that has been answered countless times. Just do not write silly code that is difficult to understand! Makes it difficult from the outset so feel sorry for the poor idiot that comes back in a few years to maintain it

Comment: This has nothing to do with macros. It has everything to do with a question that's been asked here about 2,000 times.

Comment: [C operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Comment: @ShaZiv: This has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: @FredLarson maybe the more interesting part of the question doesn't have to do with it, but for elaboration he should know that `++` comes before `*` (Dereferencing) which comes before `*` (Multiplication)

Comment: @ShaZiv: Which all doesn't matter because the expression is riddled with undefined behavior, making the precedence moot.

Comment: @FredLarson, I accept what your'e saying

Comment: as undefined behaviour is result of wrong construction of statement, so what are the rules of right construction of statement

Answer (score 0):

Your program results in undefined behaviour. `j` could be anything.

Read more here: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: as undefined behaviour is result of wrong construction of statement, so what are the rules of right construction of statement

Answer (score -1):

What I believe is happening is this.

1. Set `a` to 4.
2. `mul` is called and `a` is passed in.
3. The second multiplication (`++x`) has the prefix incrementer, so `x` (`a`) is increased by 1. `a` is now 5.
4. The multiplication now happens. Since the first and last have the postfix incrementer, nothing happens until after the multiplication happens. So we have 5 * 5 * 5 = 125.
5. Since the multiplication is done now, the postfix incrementers happen which makes `x` (`a`) 6 and then 7.
6. `j` then equals 125.
7. ???
8. Profit!

EDIT:
This is explaining the behavior that he is experiencing. I understand that this won't happen in every case.

Comment: You skipped the part where the answer is not necessarily going to be the same on other systems, or other versions of the compiler.

Comment: True...my bad. Multitasking so kinda just answered what his was doing.

Comment: The order of evaluation is not defined: "Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression." §5/4